Analogue of numpy indices for lua multidimensional array
In numpy any ndarray can be accessed by specifying a tuple of integers.  So if we build an array with arbitrary dimensions and populate it using a formula that is based on the indices of an element, it is straightforward to access an element by supplying a tuple with the element's indices:
import numpy as np

a = np.zeros((5,4,3,2))
def ivalue(index):
  return (index[0]-index[3])/(index[1]+index[2]+1)

for index, _ in np.ndenumerate(a):
    a[index] = ivalue(index)

index = (0,3,2,1)

print(a[index])  // -1/6

In lua it is relatively easy to construct the same array. For example
a = {}
for i=1, 5 do
    a[i] = {}
    for j=1, 4 do
        a[i][j] = {}
        for k=1, 3 do
            a[i][j][k] = {}
            for l=1, 2 do
                a[i][j][k][l] = (i-l)/(j+k-1)         
            end
        end
    end
end

io.write(a[1][4][3][2]) -- -1/6

But now suppose we had to write a program where given the indices we want to return a value; in numpy this is straightforward since (as long as index matches the array structure) we can write a[index] and we are done. But in lua I cannot think of a way where given index={1,4,3,2} I could retrieve the value stored. Native python has the same issue so I was thinking perhaps there is an extension of lua that deals with multidimensional array indices.

Can't you just iterate on index, applying the scalar index recursively?  That's how I'd do it with nested python lists.  a[index] is expressed as a.__getitem__(index).  That's ok if a is a numpy array, but raises a value error if a is a list, and index is a tuple.  But you could write your own subclass on list that handles a tuple arg.

Do you realize that this numpy indexing is just part of a whole multi-dimensional class, not just just an incidential addon  to python lists?  Your array creation could be done with one 'broadcasted' array calculation: res = (np.arange(5)[:,None,None,None] - np.arange(2)) / (np.arange(4)[:,None,None] + np.arange(3)[:,None] +1)

There's a numpy module, index_tricks that uses __getitem__ methods to create useful tools.  For example, idx=np.ogrid[0:5,0:4,0:3,0:2] can make 4 arrays that broadcast in the same way: res=(idx[0]-idx[3])/(idx[1]+idx[2]+1).

@hpaulj thanks for your comments. How would one apply the scalar index recursively for a lua table?

I don't know lua, but can give you a function that works with the equivalent nested python list.
Make the array with broadcasted arrays:
In [303]: res = (np.arange(5)[:,None,None,None] -
    np.arange(2))/(np.arange(4)[:,None,None] +
    np.arange(3)[:,None]+1)
In [304]: res.shape
Out[304]: (5, 4, 3, 2)

Make a nested list from that:
In [305]: lres = res.tolist()    
In [306]: len(lres), len(lres[0][0])
Out[306]: (5, 3)

An iterative function to apply successive indices:
def foo(a, idx):
    res = a
    if len(idx)==0:
        return res
    for i in idx:
        res = res[idx[0]]
        idx = idx[1:]
    return res

testing with index:
In [311]: index = (4,3,2,1)

The array version:
In [312]: res[index]
Out[312]: 0.5

trying the tuple on the nested list:
In [313]: lres[index]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[313], line 1
----> 1 lres[index]

TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple

But the function:
In [314]: foo(lres, index)
Out[314]: 0.5

it also works on the array (but not quite as fast):
In [315]: foo(res, index)
Out[315]: 0.5

A recursive equivalent:
def foor(a, idx):
    if len(idx)==0:
        return a
    else:
        return foor(a[idx[0]], idx[1:])

In [317]: foor(lres, index)
Out[317]: 0.5  

From the little I've seen about lua you should be able to translate one or both without too much trouble.  Looks like its table is similar to list.
There are about 300 questions/answers on SO with searching for [lua] array.  So people have been working with some sort of arrays in lua - though in many cases that may be just another name for table.
In python deeply nested lists are not common.  One level of nesting is common enough.  There are even tricks for 'transposing` such a list
In [318]: alist = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]; alist
Out[318]: [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]

In [319]: list(zip(*alist))
Out[319]: [(1, 4), (2, 5), (3, 6)]

Under the covers, numpy stores all the values in a flat (1d) array ('C'), and uses shape and strides to treat it as a multidimensional array.
An alternative to creating a deeply nested list, would be to make a flat one, and use a bit of math to convert index to a flat equivalent.
numpy has a function to calculate a flat index from a multidimensional one:
In [320]: np.ravel_multi_index(index, res.shape)
Out[320]: 119    
In [321]: res.ravel()[119]
Out[321]: 0.5

In this direction the calculation is easy, it's the reverse that's a bit trickier.
In [324]: res.strides
Out[324]: (192, 48, 16, 8)
In [325]: np.multiply(index, res.strides).sum()/8
Out[325]: 119.0


If you want to access your multi-dimensional table's items by a 'tuple' of keys, you have to define a new object, with access operations reloaded this way. Technically, this object will also be a table (in Lua, almost everyting of interest is a table); but it ought to have a metatable with two metamethods: __newindex to reload table item setter and __index to reload the getter.
local function indexed_by_tuple (multidimensional)
    -- Non-tables should not be wrapped:
    if type (multidimensional) ~= 'table' then
        return multidimensional
    end
    return setmetatable ({}, {
        __newindex = function (tbl, keys, value)
            -- We want the standard syntax z [i] [j] [k] [l] to still work:
            local keys = type (keys) == 'table' and keys or { keys }        
            local current = multidimensional
            for depth, key in ipairs (keys) do
                -- Last key reached:
                if depth == #keys then
                    current[key] = value
                    break
                end
                -- Sub-table not initialised yet:
                if current [key] == nil then
                    current[key] = {}
                end
                -- Going deeper:
                current = current[key]
            end
        end,
        __index = function (tbl, keys)
        -- We want the standard syntax z [i] [j] [k] [l] to still work:     
        local keys = type (keys) == 'table' and keys or { keys }
        local current = multidimensional
        for depth, key in ipairs (keys) do
            -- Last key reached:
            if depth == #keys then
                -- Allow to index the return with a tuple as well:
                return indexed_by_tuple (current [key])
            end
            -- Even the dimension is not initialised yet:
            if current [key] == nil then
                return nil
            end
            -- Go deeper:
            current = current [key]
        end
    end
    })
end

-- A 4-d test table:
local a = {}
for i = 1, 5 do
    a [i] = {}
    for j = 1, 4 do
        a [i] [j] = {}
        for k = 1, 3 do
            a [i] [j] [k] = {}
            for l= 1, 2 do
                a [i] [j] [k] [l] = (i - l) / ( j + k - 1 )
            end
        end
    end
end

-- Initialise table indexed by tuple with a table:
local ibt = indexed_by_tuple (a)

-- Reset one item by hand:
ibt [{ 1, 3, 3, 1 }] = 42

-- Get an item by tuple:
print ('ibt [{ 1, 3, 3, 1 }] = ', ibt [{ 1, 3, 3, 1 }])
-- Get it traditional way:
print ('ibt [1] [3] [3] [1] = ', ibt [1] [3] [3] [1])
-- Get it mixed way:
print ('ibt [1] [{ 3, 3, 1 }] = ', ibt [1] [{ 3, 3, 1 }])
print ('ibt [{ 1, 3 }] [{ 3, 1 }] = ', ibt [{ 1, 3 }] [{ 3, 1 }])

-- Set an item mixed way:
ibt [{ 1, 3 }] [3] [1] = 21
-- Get it tuple way:
print ('ibt [{ 1, 3, 3, 1 }] = ', ibt [{ 1, 3, 3, 1 }])
-- Set an item mixed, but opposite, way:
ibt [1] [3] [{ 3, 1 }] = 14
-- Get it tuple way:
print ('ibt [{ 1, 3, 3, 1 }] = ', ibt [{ 1, 3, 3, 1 }])

-- More test cases:
for _, key in ipairs {
    { 1, 4, 3, 2 },
    { 1, 1, 1, 1 },
    { 2, 3, 4, 5 }, -- was never set, so nil.
    { 5, 4, 3, 2 }
} do
    print ( 'ibt [{ ' .. table.concat (key, ', ') .. ' }] = ', ibt [key])
end

